# Issue with Vagrant apache2 cookbook

Tags: apache, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

Issue that i have is about starting vagrant on some older project. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and vagrant worked fine until i installed ssd on my laptop (not sure if related).

So when i do Vagrant up i get the following message:

```
==> default: * directory[/etc/apache2/ssl] action create
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/ssl] created directory /etc/apache2/ssl
==> default:     
==> default: - create new directory /etc/apache2/ssl
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/ssl] owner changed to 0
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/ssl] group changed to 0
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/ssl] mode changed to 755
==> default:     
==> default: - change mode from '' to '0755'
==> default:     - change owner from '' to 'root'
==> default:     - change group from '' to 'root'
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default:   
==> default: * directory[/etc/apache2/conf.d] action create
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/conf.d] created directory /etc/apache2/conf.d
==> default:     
==> default: - create new directory /etc/apache2/conf.d
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/conf.d] owner changed to 0
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/conf.d] group changed to 0
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:27+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/apache2/conf.d] mode changed to 755
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: - change mode from '' to '0755'
==> default:     - change owner from '' to 'root'
==> default:     - change group from '' to 'root'
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default:   
==> default: * directory[/var/cache/apache2] action create
==> default:  (up to date)
==> default:   * template[/etc/sysconfig/httpd] action create
==> default:  (skipped due to only_if)
==> default:   * template[apache2.conf] action create
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:     
==> default: Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[apache2.conf]'
==> default:     
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
==> default:     
==> default: ------------------------------------
==> default:     
==> default: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: Resource Declaration:
==> default: 
==> default:     ---------------------
==> default:     # In /tmp/vagrant-chef/0ad2cd5b52108461d0c0cbda213593d4/cookbooks/!apache2/recipes/default.rb
==> default:     
==> default:     149: template 'apache2.conf' do
==> default:     150:   case node['platform_family']
==> default:     151:   when 'rhel', 'fedora', 'arch'
==> default:     152:     path "#{node['apache']['dir']}/conf/httpd.conf"
==> default:     153:   when 'debian'
==> default:     154:     path "#{node['apache']['dir']}/apache2.conf"
==> default:     155:   when 'freebsd'
==> default:     156:     path "#{node['apache']['dir']}/httpd.conf"
==> default:     157:   end
==> default:     158:   source   'apache2.conf.erb'
==> default:     
==> default:     Compiled Resource:
==> default:     ------------------
==> default:     # Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef/0ad2cd5b52108461d0c0cbda213593d4/cookbooks/!apache2/recipes/default.rb:149:in `from_file'
==> default:     
==> default:     template("apache2.conf") do
==> default:       action [:create]
==> default:       retries 0
==> default:       retry_delay 2
==> default:       default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:       path "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
==> default:       backup 5
==> default:       atomic_update true
==> default:       source "apache2.conf.erb"
==> default:       declared_type :template
==> default:       cookbook_name :apache2
==> default:     
==> default:   recipe_name "default"
==> default:     
==> default:   mode "0644"
==> default:       owner "root"
==> default:       group "root"
==> default:     end
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default:     Template Context:
==> default:     
==> default: -----------------
==> default:     on line #94
==> default:      92: # viewed by Web clients.
==> default:     
==> default:  93: #
==> default:      94: <% access_file_name_prefix = node['apache']['access_file_name'][0..2] if !node['apache']['access_file_name'].empty?
==> default: 
==> default:      95:    if access_file_name_prefix != '.ht'
==> default:      96:     file_name_prefix = '(' + access_file_name_prefix + '|\.ht)'
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:28+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default: 
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:28+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: 
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:28+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 14 resources updated in 03 minutes 07 seconds
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:28+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:28+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:28+00:00] ERROR: 
==> default: 
==> default: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass) on line #94:
==> default: 
==> default:  92: # viewed by Web clients.
==> default:  93: #
==> default:  94: <% access_file_name_prefix = node['apache']['access_file_name'][0..2] if !node['apache']['access_file_name'].empty?
==> default:  95:    if access_file_name_prefix != '.ht'
==> default:  96:     file_name_prefix = '(' + access_file_name_prefix + '|\.ht)'
==> default: 
==> default:   (erubis):94:in `block in evaluate'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `instance_eval'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `evaluate'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:162:in `_render_template'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:148:in `render_template'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider/template/content.rb:53:in `file_for_provider'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:40:in `tempfile'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:462:in `tempfile'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:339:in `do_generate_content'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:150:in `action_create'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource.rb:596:in `run_action'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `each'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block in converge'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/forwardable.rb:183:in `execute_each_resource'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:105:in `converge'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:658:in `block in converge'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `catch'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `converge'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:692:in `converge_and_save'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:271:in `run'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:261:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:215:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:203:in `run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:286:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:275:in `loop'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:275:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:253:in `run_application'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default:   /usr/bin/chef-solo:54:in `load'
==> default:   /usr/bin/chef-solo:54:in `<main>'
==> default: [2019-09-24T19:44:29+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Vagrant setup is running:

```
 config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef| 
    chef.roles_path = "./chef/chef-repo/roles" 
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["./chef/chef-repo/cookbooks"] 
    chef.data_bags_path = "./chef/chef-repo/data_bags"
    chef.environments_path = "./chef/chef-repo/environments"
      chef.add_recipe "apt"
      chef.add_recipe "chef_gem"
      chef.add_recipe "base"
      chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
      chef.add_recipe "openssl"
      chef.add_recipe "apache2"
      chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_php5"
      chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_rewrite"
      chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_ssl"
      chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
      chef.add_recipe "mysql::client"
      chef.add_recipe "mysql_charset"
      chef.add_recipe "php"
      chef.add_recipe "memcached"
      chef.add_recipe "php::module_mysql"
      chef.add_recipe "php::module_curl"
      chef.add_recipe "php::module_gd"
      chef.add_recipe "php::module_memcache"
      chef.add_recipe "deploy"
      chef.environment = "vagrant"
```

and apache2 part is failing.

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apache2/versions/1.1.16

This is cookbook for apache2.
Any idea on reason of failing? Works on different computer, same version of vbox, vagrant, ruby.

Answer (score 0):

So the error is caused by this erb template line (scroll to the right):

```
#==> default:      94: <% access_file_name_prefix = node['apache']['access_file_name'][0..2] if !node['apache']['access_file_name'].empty?
```

the error is `` undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass `` so after reading the template line, it's pretty clear what causes the error:

Somewhere in your recipes, attributes, roles, environments something is setting `node['apache']['access_file_name']` to `nil` instead of just an empty string (`""`).

You also seem to use a very, very, very old version of the cookbook (1.1.16) which is 7 (seven) years old.